# 400 Bad request when calling Rest WebService POST method

Tags: java, rest, jersey, weblogic12c

I am creating the client for the Rest-full WS(deveoped with JAX-RS , Jersey) . On invoking POST method

Server : Weblogic 12.2.1 , it uses Jersey 2.xx

I am getting exception as

`InboundJaxrsResponse{context=ClientResponse{method=POST, uri=http://localhost:8070/Handset/api/activate, status=400, reason=Bad Request}}`

Also the GET method request is working fine from the WS client.

Below is the Web service code :-

```
@GET
@Path("/verify")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response verifyRESTService(InputStream incomingData) {
    String result = "RESTService Successfully started..";

    // return HTTP response 200 in case of success
    return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
}

@POST
@Path("/activate")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public MyResponse activate(final Activate model, @Context HttpServletRequest request) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String,String> requestMap = m.convertValue(model, Map.class);

 Map<String, String> responseMap= new HashMap<String, String>();
            Status responseStatus = new Status();   

            try {
                responseMap=service(requestMap,request);

                if(responseMap.containsKey("returnCode"))
                    responseStatus.setReturnCode(responseMap.get("returnCode"));

                if(responseMap.containsKey("errorDescription"))
                    responseStatus.setErrorDescription(responseMap.get("errorDescription"));

                if(responseMap.containsKey("errorCode"))
                    responseStatus.setErrorCode(responseMap.get("errorCode"));

            } catch (ServletException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

MyResponse obj = new ServiceModel();
((ServiceModel)obj).setStatus(responseStatus);  
  return obj;
  }
```

Below are the response classes :-

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "status")
public class Status {
private String returnCode;
private String errorDescription;
private String errorCode;




@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "response")
public class ServiceModel implements MyResponse  {
private Status status;

}
```

Below is Java Client for POST Request using Jersey API :-

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget webTarget=null;

            Activate activate = new Activate();
            activate.setToken("112233445566");
            activate.setEmpID("999999");
            activate.setService("TIMPersonal");

            webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8070/Handset/api").path("activate");

            Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder =  webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
            Response activateServiceResponse = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.entity(activate, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
```

However when I am hitiing request from postman POST request is working fine
[image]

Below jars have used to develop WS client.

[image]

Below jars have been used to develop Rest-full WS

[image]

Model class :- Activate is created both at client and server location with same structure as follows

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
   public class Activate {
      private String token;
      private String empId;
      private String service;
```

I am not sure on how to frame application/xml request from java client . 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add code for `activateService`

Comment: Have edited the post to include complete ActivateService model class. 
Same class has been created  used at the client  side to map xml request params as hardcoded in the java client code in post.

Comment: code for the method `activateService()`

Comment: You have just added the method signature of the activateService() method

Comment: oh ok , have added the code along with the response classes

Comment: have you tried using the logs or Wireshark to see what the actual request looks like?

Comment: The `m` should be capitalized in `getmWallet` and `setmWallet` or add `@XmlElement(name="mWalletToken")` to the property